# Regexp for parsing HTML emails failing at catching more than one element

Tags: html, ruby, regex

I'm trying to parse PayPal HTML emails to pick up the different items. For instance, there is a  in which all the bought items are displayed, with their price, units and total.

This is the `<table>` I'm trying to parse:

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="clear:both;color:#333!important;font-size:12px;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif" width="598px">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-left:none;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px!important;color:#333333" width="348" align="left">Description</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-left:none;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px!important;color:#333333" width="100" align="right">Unit price</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-left:none;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px!important;color:#333333" width="50" align="right">Qty</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-left:none;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px!important;color:#333333" width="80" align="right">Amount</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px"><a href="http://cgi.ebay.es/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&amp;item=171154674852" target="_blank">FUNDA PIEL FUCSIA PARA BQ AQUARIUS 4.5. GRAN CALIDAD.</a><br>Item# 171154674852</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">€3,50 EUR</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">1</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">€3,50 EUR</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px"><a href="http://cgi.ebay.es/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&amp;item=171154674852" target="_blank">FUNDA PIEL ROJA PARA IPHONE 4.5. GRAN CALIDAD.</a><br>Item# 171154674852</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">€10,50 EUR</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">1</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">€10,50 EUR</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I use match to detect and catch the different vars (Ruby):

```
unless /thePreviousRegexp/.match(body).nil?
    item = /thePreviousRegexp/.match(body)[:item]
    price_unit = /thePreviousRegexp/.match(body)[:price_unit]
end
```

Ok, it works when i just have one item. But, when I have more than one it just takes the last one. I want to catch all of them.

How could i do it? I put the < tr > that belongs to the table among ()+ which means that pattern could repeat itself by one or more times. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Tell me what are the information you want to grab from your example html?

Comment: You already solved the problem. Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**Nokogiri**](http://nokogiri.org/).

I would do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-eot
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="clear:both;color:#333!important;font-size:12px;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif" width="598px">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-left:none;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px!important;color:#333333" width="348" align="left">Description</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-left:none;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px!important;color:#333333" width="100" align="right">Unit price</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-left:none;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px!important;color:#333333" width="50" align="right">Qty</td>
         <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-left:none;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px!important;color:#333333" width="80" align="right">Amount</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px"><a href="http://cgi.ebay.es/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&amp;item=171154674852" target="_blank">FUNDA PIEL FUCSIA PARA BQ AQUARIUS 4.5. GRAN CALIDAD.</a><br>Item# 171154674852</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">€3,50 EUR</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">1</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">€3,50 EUR</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px"><a href="http://cgi.ebay.es/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&amp;item=171154674852" target="_blank">FUNDA PIEL ROJA PARA IPHONE 4.5. GRAN CALIDAD.</a><br>Item# 171154674852</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">€10,50 EUR</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">1</td>
         <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-bottom:none;padding:10px">€10,50 EUR</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
eot

table_header = doc.xpath("//table//tr[1]/td").map(&:text)
# => ["Description", "Unit price", "Qty", "Amount"]

product_information = doc.xpath("//table//tr[position()!=1]").map do |e|
  Hash[table_header.zip(e.css('td').map(&:text))]
end

product_information
# => [{"Description"=>
#       "FUNDA PIEL FUCSIA PARA BQ AQUARIUS 4.5. GRAN CALIDAD.Item# 171154674852",
#      "Unit price"=>"€3,50 EUR",
#      "Qty"=>"1",
#      "Amount"=>"€3,50 EUR"},
#     {"Description"=>
#       "FUNDA PIEL ROJA PARA IPHONE 4.5. GRAN CALIDAD.Item# 171154674852",
#      "Unit price"=>"€10,50 EUR",
#      "Qty"=>"1",
#      "Amount"=>"€10,50 EUR"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `match` You need to use `exec` method and repeat it with `while` loop.
Use only short regex like this:

```
/item=(\d*?)\".*?€([\d\,]+) EUR/g
```

Hope it helps, but not in criminal activity.

Comment: Don't worry about that. It's just to offer a great feature to my clients. I'm trying to parse the invoice to store it in an invoice app.

Comment: Sure, no problem. :) If there is need to change this regex, please inform me, I will be glad to help. :)

Comment: I am too weak in `RegEx`..!